# Refrence to ... is ambigous!! / C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
protected:
    long studentID;
public:
    void setStudentID(long s_){ studentID = s_; }
    Student(): studentID(0){}
    long get_StudentID(){ return studentID; }
};

class Exam : public Student
{
protected:
    float mark;
public:
    void setMark(float m_){ mark = m_; }
    Exam(): mark(0){}
    float getMark(){ return mark; }
};

class Sports : public Student
{
protected:
    float score;
public:
    void setScore(float s_){ score = s_; }
    Sports(): score(0){}
    float getScore(){ return score; }
};

class Result: public Student, public Exam, public Sports
{
private:
    float Total;
public:
    float getTotal(){ return getMark() * getScore(); }
    void display();
};

void Result::display()
{
    cout << "Student ID = " << get_StudentID() << endl;
    cout << "Exam Mark = " << getMark() << endl;
    cout << "Sports Score = " << getScore() << endl;
    cout << "Total Mark = " << getTotal();
}

int main()
{
    Result st1;
    st1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code in Code::Blocks and it's incomplete yet , but this error that says "refrence to get_StudentID is ambigous" confused me; What's wrong with it?
Should I delete using namespace and insert std:: before all (cout, cin & endl) statments?

Comment: First,  `Sports`, an`Exam` and a `Result` are all not a `Student`, so none of them should inherit from `Student`.  You should only derive from a class when the derived class has an *is a* relationship with the class it is inheriting from.

Comment: Why do your classes all inherit from `Student`? Anyway, `get_StudentID()` is ambiguous because you're inheriting from `Student` multiple times (directly and indirectly)

Comment: Inheritance is not a golden hammer. Your code architecture is wrong. Instead inheritance use composition.

Comment: When you call `get_StudentID()` in the `Result::display` routine, which `get_StudentID` do you expect?  The `Student::get_StudentID()` one, or the `Exam::Student::get_StudentID()` one, or the `Sports::Student::get_StudentID()` one?  The code is an example of using inheritance as a golden footgun.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding inheritance. For example, the class `Exam` with this line

```cpp
class Exam : public virtual Student
```

is publicly inheriting from Student. Public inheritance should only be used in an [IS-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. In this case, `Exam` **is not** a `Student` so you shouldn't use public inheritance. Same goes for `Sports`.

"Call is ambiguous" means that when you call `get_StudentID` from `Result` the compiler can't decide between `Exam::get_StudentID` or `Sports::get_StudentID` which they both inherit from `Student`.

Instead:
Remove the inheritance, don't use inheritance anywhere here. I would completely remake this and make a `Student` class with `Exam` and `Sports` member objects (which can become vector of objects later if needed) and call the needed functions from the member objects instead. *As a general tip, avoid multiple inheritance unless completely necessary.*

Comment: I agree but " As a general tip, avoid multiple inheritance unless completely necessary." seems a little bit restrictive. There are guidelines to use multiple inheritance (example : [C.135 - C.136](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-mi-interface))

Comment: @Ben_LCDB Agreed. I guess avoid is a strong word for this. "Consider alternatives" might've been better

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix

1. remove Student from Results base class
2. make Student `public virtual` from both Exam and Sports class

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
protected:
    long studentID;
public:
    void setStudentID(long s_){ studentID = s_; }
    Student(): studentID(0){}
    long get_StudentID(){ return studentID; }
};

class Exam : public virtual Student
{
protected:
    float mark;
public:
    void setMark(float m_){ mark = m_; }
    Exam(): mark(0){}
    float getMark(){ return mark; }
};

class Sports : public virtual Student
{
protected:
    float score;
public:
    void setScore(float s_){ score = s_; }
    Sports(): score(0){}
    float getScore(){ return score; }
};

class Result: public Exam, public Sports
{
private:
    float Total;
public:
    float getTotal(){ return getMark() * getScore(); }
    void display();
};

void Result::display()
{
    cout << "Student ID = " << get_StudentID() << endl;
    cout << "Exam Mark = " << getMark() << endl;
    cout << "Sports Score = " << getScore() << endl;
    cout << "Total Mark = " << getTotal();
}

int main()
{
    Result st1;
    st1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4f5n8M5of

Comment: It doesn't make sense for there to be any inheritance here. An exam might be associated with a student, but it isn't a student itself.

Comment: I'm just answering the C++ logic question, not the overall merit of their assignment.